# Does Edward Witten propose that all symmetries are emergent?

Tags: particle-physics, symmetry, gauge-invariance, laws-of-physics

Some authors (like Holger B Nielsen, Robert B Laughlin, David Pines, John Wheeler...) have proposed that all fundamental symmetries and laws of physics are not really fundamental but rather emergent.

I have found [an article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01791) by Witten where he seems to propose that all symmetries are emergent. Does anyone know if he is actually proposing that?

Comment: Upside down. Mathematics emerges from axioms, but the foundations of physics are real phenomena. Witten works as far from fundamental physics as he possibly can.